# Alternative to fat jar in gradle java project

Tags: java, gradle

I have started on gradle today itself. So I am trying out random things. I have below `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
 
dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.2')
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(
      'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.demo.Hello'
    )
  }
  from {
     configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}        
   }
}
```

I have read somewhere that the method that I am using inside `from` block will create fat jar, which is not a good practice. As I am fairly new to this, I humbly want to ask the alternative to this. Is it adding classpath to manifest or something else??

The primary purpose is to bundle third party dependency jar files that will be used on runtime.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your dependencies into a ZIP file together with your own JAR and possibly external resources, or build an installer, or (if you're building a web app) build a WAR or EAR file. Gradle will take care of the manifest for you in any case.

(Also, there is nothing really wrong with fat JARs, they are fairly common these days and they do work.)

Comment: Would you please tell me the way to do what you have written( the ZIP way). I mean any change in build.gradle

Comment: Use the Zip plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.html

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI If you're using Java 9+ you can create a custom runtime image with `jlink`. If you're using Java 14 you can create a native executable or installer with `jpackage` (currently incubating). Note both create _platform-specific_, self-contained applications. Since you're using Gradle you can make using the aforementioned tools easier with the [badass-jlink-plugin](https://github.com/beryx/badass-jlink-plugin).

Comment: @VIPULTYAGI Also, to make creating fat/uber jars easier you can use the [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).